# Why does Power Query not honor the sort in the output table when loaded to the data model?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm using Excel 365 and pulling in a table via Power Query. In the underlying SQL, I use an ORDER BY clause to sort the data, which works correctly in the PowerQuery preview and in my SQL client. But I noticed the table that winds up getting loaded in Excel isn't sorted in the same order. I added a sort step to Power Query as the final step, and it *still* didn't work, even after I wrapped the step in Table.Buffer(). I have also tried it with and without the Preserve column order/sort checkbox checked.

It only honors the sort settings if I uncheck the box to load the query into the data model.

How can I make it follow the sort as specified and load into the data model?

Comment: You can also check the sorting options in Power Pivot (data model)

Comment: That's what I said - it ignores the sort settings in Power Query. I am not using a pivot table, so Power Pivot is irrelevant.

Comment: Actually it isn’t. When you add a table to the data model you’re using Power Pivot